# D3.js color by boolean values

Tags: d3.js

I have the following tsv setup with fips codes as ID, and I want to color counties based on Sample1, Sample2, and shared between Sample1 and Sample2:

```
    id      Sample1     Sample2
    1031    1           0
    1032    1           0
    1033    1           1
```

So far, I can fill counties based on Sample1 or Sample2, but not together. Here is my code:

```
var rateById = d3.map();
var quantize = d3.scale.quantize()
    .domain([1, 1000]) 
    .range(d3.range(9).map(function(i) { return "q" + i + "-9"; }));
var projection = d3.geo.albersUsa()
    .scale(3960) 
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);
var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);
queue()
    .defer(d3.json, "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mbostock/4090846/raw/d534aba169207548a8a3d670c9c2cc719ff05c47/us.json")
    .defer(d3.tsv, "Example.tsv", function(d) { rateById.set(d.id, +d.Sample1); })
    .await(ready);
function ready(error, us) {
  if (error) throw error;
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "counties")
    .selectAll("path")
      .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.counties).features)
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", function(d) { return quantize(rateById.get(d.id)); })
    .attr("d", path);
  svg.append("path")
      .datum(topojson.mesh(us, us.objects.states, function(a, b) { return a !== b; }))
      .attr("class", "states")
      .attr("d", path);
}
d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", height + "px");
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Your color is based on value from 1 to 1000.  What would a combined color look like?  Do you want to add the numbers?  Shade half the state with each value?  Add both colors with opacity so they "show through"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I ended up solving this:

```
.defer(d3.tsv, "Example.tsv", function(d) {
    if (d.Sample1 > 0 && d.Sample2 > 0) d.color = "saddlebrown"; 
    else if (d.Sample1 > 0) d.color = "green"; 
    else if (d.Sample2 > 0) d.color = "mediumpurple";
    else d.color = "lightgrey";
    rateById.set(d.id, d.color);
})
```

It compares whether Sample1 and Sample2 are both present and colors based on their values.  [It produces this map like I want.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKt1O.jpg)